# HTML Horizontal Navigation UL not filling space

Tags: html, css, navbar

Please help with this problem.

This navigation bar will not work properly and every browser displays it differently.. What am I doing wrong? Is this code not to proper specification? and I don't want to have to set a static height for all the a, li, and ul accordingly... shouldn't they fill up with the text? i don't know what I am doing wrong he text combined with `<a>` tags in the `<li>`.

Please see the fiddle for example. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/z2Kcx/

Comment: How do you want it to look **exactly**?

Comment: Could this be just a background issue? If so, just add `#nav li { background-color: #333;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a clearfix to `#nav` - 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2Kcx/2/)

```
#nav::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```